# Trying to access an object's member data - undefined even after initiation, what's wrong?

Tags: c++, class, object

```
if(GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) && Player1.canFire == true)
{
    Player1.canFire = false;
    Player1.hasFired = true;
    Bullet Bullet1((Player1.Xpos + (Player1.Skin->GetWidth() / 2)), 
                    Player1.Ypos - ProjectileSkin->GetHeight() );
}
if(Player1.hasFired = true)
{
    Bullet1.Projectile->CopyTo(m_Screen, Bullet1.m_xPos, Bullet1.m_yPos);
    Bullet1.m_yPos -= 5;
}
```

Where I say `Bullet1.Projectile->CopyTo`, I get the error that `Bullet1` not is defined, but I have instantiated it in the if block above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No we don't, Bulltet1 is not in scope in the second block.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Bullet1` becomes out of scope by the time it reaches line 9. You need to move the `Bullet1` variable declaration outside the `if` statement.

However, I don't quite see the point of putting the second `if` statement at all if you require `Bullet1` to be initialized anyways. So,

```
if(GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) && Player1.canFire == true)
{
    Player1.canFire = false;
    Player1.hasFired = true;
    Bullet Bullet1((Player1.Xpos + (Player1.Skin->GetWidth() / 2)), 
                Player1.Ypos - ProjectileSkin->GetHeight() );
    Bullet1.Projectile->CopyTo(m_Screen, Bullet1.m_xPos, Bullet1.m_yPos);
    Bullet1.m_yPos -= 5;
}
```

Comment: alright, but i only want it to initialize when that certain thing is true, because the xPos should only be set to the position of player1 when he just presses the button to fire, so that i can move the player itself without the bullet moving along on the x axis when it is flying,if you know what i mean ?

Comment: declare `Bullet1` as a pointer then initialize it will `NULL`. That way, you can check in the second `if` statement whether the `Bullet1` has been initialized or not.

Comment: put `Bullet *Bullet1 = NULL` outside the `if`statements, then put `Bullet1 = new Bullet((Player1.Xpos +(Player1.Skin->GetWidth() / 2)), Player1.Ypos - ProjectileSkin->GetHeight() );` in the first scope, then in the second scope, surround the code with another `if` statement, `if( Bullet1 ){...}`. Don't forget to clean it up at the end by calling `if( Bullet1 ) delete Bullet1;`

Comment: nvm i see your new comment now

Comment: Never mind, i basically made a custom Init function inside the class, so i define Bullet1 in global scope now, without having to worry about passing it vars that shouldnt have yet

Comment: @user1686825 Yes. that would also be a solution. Just keep in mind that whenever you declare a variable within a scope, you can't access it from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bullet Bullet1((Player1.Xpos + (Player1.Skin->GetWidth() / 2)), 
                    Player1.Ypos - ProjectileSkin->GetHeight() );
```

You bullet is a local variable. It will end with }. The possible solution is to not create is locally. or send it to both function as a argument.

Also there is a serious mistake here:

if(Player1.hasFired = true)

it should be ==

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `Bullet1` is only within the `IF` block. If you want to use it in the other `IF` block as well, define it outside as follows:

```
Bullet Bullet1((Player1.Xpos + (Player1.Skin->GetWidth() / 2)), 
                Player1.Ypos - ProjectileSkin->GetHeight() );
if(GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) && Player1.canFire == true)
{
    Player1.canFire = false;
    Player1.hasFired = true;
}
if(Player1.hasFired = true)
{
    Bullet1.Projectile->CopyTo(m_Screen, Bullet1.m_xPos, Bullet1.m_yPos);
    Bullet1.m_yPos -= 5;
}
```